# Copy photos from iPhone straight to USB via Macbook

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, photos

I plugged my iPhone and a USB Flash Drive into my MacBook.

How can I copy all the photos on the phone straight onto the USB drive?

Photos.app only gives me the option to "Import" photos to albums, which are physically on my MacBook.

Answer (score 2):

With the Image Capture utility.  You can copy pictures from the iOS device without having to import them into Photos.app.